# How to extract map center coordinates from Geocoder?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

```
var address = "Boston";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
        createLatLng();
    } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }

});

function createLatLng() {
  var MapCenter=map.getCenter();
  var x=MapCenter.lat(), y=MapCenter.lng(), z=0;
}
```

right now I have this code, mostly taken from this example at google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding.

Right now the x and y variables are undefined. Why is this and how can I get the x and y variables correctly?

also here is demo if it helps: http://jsbin.com/ilOTIQIn/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `geocode` is asynchronous you're not going to be able to set `MapCenter` at the place you want to because the results of the API call won't have returned at that point. I suggest you use a `callback` to help you manage the call:

```
var MapCenter, map, x, y, z;

function geocode(callback) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
      callback();
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

geocode(function () {
  MapCenter = map.getCenter();
  x = MapCenter.lat(), y = MapCenter.lng(), z = 0;
});
```

Comment: hmm well your code results in x and y being undefined which I don't really understand because the geocode function is called? but I will try and study it further.

Comment: see updated question. I realize it is slightly different than the way you did it but they both produce the same incorrect output.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 Check the console log for [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ATppL/5/). This is producing `x` and `y` properly, and this is a replica of the code above. The only change is that I've passed the address into the geocode function as a parameter.

Comment: I just modified your fiddle slightly by adding divA and printing out x into it. http://jsfiddle.net/ATppL/6/. As you can see it comes out as undefined. Is this the result you are getting?

Comment: [It has to be in the callback](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ATppL/8/). You're finding the same problem you had earlier; trying to assign something to a variable the value of which hasn't been returned yet.

Comment: Ah, but it doesn't have to be in the callback, but there has to be, say, [a call to another function that updates your `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/ATppL/9/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Just remember, the majority of API calls are asynchronous. Callbacks/deferred objects/promises are vital in these circumstances If you don't understand any of these terms, go look them up, there are loads of tutorials available. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is an asynchronous language. Your geocode request gets sent off, and while that's happening, your x,y, and z vars are evaluated. Your geocode result then returns, but the x, y and z vars have already been set. I would define your x,y,z vars above the function, then , where you check if the status is 'ok' set them there.

perceived order of events:

1. send off request
2. request returns
3. set variables x, y z

actual order of events:

1. Send off request
2. Set variables x, y, z
3. result returns

Comment: how can I check if the status is 'ok' (the results have been returned). With this?: if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

Comment: Close, i would use

if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
//dostuff
}

That way you do a deep compare on the strings :)